# Responsive website - text scaling

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, web

I am trying to create a responsive website. 
The issue im having is that the image widths are decreasing in size when I make the window smaller (which is good) but the text on the images move to a different location. 
How can I get the text AND image to scale down together when decreasing the size of the window.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="column1">
            <img src="">
            <div class="row-welcome">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <p>Hello, Welcome to my web site</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

.row-welcome p {
color: blue;
margin-top: -100px;
margin-left: 200px;
font-size: 10px;
```

}

Comment: This would benefit greatly from actual code (there's no `@media` query shown anywhere in this) and screenshots of what you see and what you expect.

Comment: ceejayoz, it doesn't need to use @media rule as it can be solved with some css rules that are causing the issue...

Comment: What do you mean by scaling? Having actually decreasing the font-size or just keeping the text contained within the borders of the image?

Comment: @Green123, you're only showing the style for p tag that wouldn't be sufficent to help you...

Comment: @BhojendraNepal You want to make a responsive site without `@media` queries? Good luck!

Comment: @ceejayoz, sorry but you're not understand me and the OP. OP meant to be responsive as zoom-in zoom-out the browser...

Comment: I'm sorry i didnt mean to make you all think i didnt want to you @media queries... I just don't know where to go with this. My issue is not the size of the font when i ammaking the screen smaller.. is that the <p> is moving upwards completely when i decrease the size of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `vw`. It is supported in every browser except opera mini and some issues with IE. http://www.sitepoint.com/new-css3-relative-font-size/ and http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

You may use @media queries to change body font size if using vw does not fit you.

You also need to change all your values in pixels to %, em, vw or some relative values so it all be on the same scale while scaling.

And I advise you to set min and max font size and/or test on different screen resolutions (from 480*320 mobile to 2560*1440) or you may have unexpected results.

Comment: Hello, yes vw is doing its job - however, the issue is that the <p> is decreasing in font size which is fine - but it is completely moving in location - like the <p> is moving upwards when i make the screen smaller

Comment: @Green123 you should not use px for positioning if you want text to stay in relatively same position to the image, will using some relative positioning (with %, vw/vh or em) help? Or I may not understand your question right so provide examples as images to show what is wrong.